# environment specific variables in pingfederate templates

Tags: deployment, environment-variables, pingfederate

I am customizing a pingfederate temaplte (for login).

As part of this customization I would like to be able to have a java script variable that is dependent on the configuration of the form being used. Essentially to distinguish between a test and a live environment.

I'm trying to keep the templates in source control and not have duplicated code and also to be able to test configurations before I deploy.

I'd like to think that I could set a variable somewhere in the admin interface and get this exposed in the template, however I have found nothing in the documentation to suggest that this is possible.

Is there a way to do this, or a reasonable work around?

Answer (score 1):

From the perspective of PingFederate itself, no. There are plenty of mechanisms in Javascript that you could use, like `window.location.host` to trigger CSS properties. You could even use the Velocity variable of `$PingFedBaseURL` to drive CSS properties.

Comment: There are plenty of js and CSS ways. But they don't allow code to be separate from config.

Comment: Why would they need to be? Just check the javascript or Velocity variables for matches of prod-sso.abc.com or dev-sso.abc.com, and then apply the approriate CSS change...